# additional None in output of print in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to invoke some methods defined in testlib.py, confused why there is additional 'None' in output? Thanks.

**Code where I invoke testlib.py**

```
print testlib.globalFoo()
f = testlib.Foo()
print f.getValue()
```

**testlib.py**

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def getValue(self):
        print 'get value in class Foo'

def globalFoo():
    print 'in global foo'
```

**Output**,

```
in global foo
None <= confusion here
get value in class Foo
None <= confusion here
```

Comment: This is a case of using Functions for "Side Effect"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause is that you are printing the result of a function that doesn't return anything and only has a `print` statement. Any function that doesn't explicitly return something will implicitly return `None`.

```
>>> def say_hello():
...   print 'hello!'
... 
>>> print say_hello()
hello!
None
>>> h = say_hello()
hello!
>>> print h
None
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `print testlib.globalFoo()`, the function itself is doing the printing (specifically "in global foo"). Then, the function returns nothing (or `None`), and that is what your print is showing. If you're only wanting to print once, simply call the function with `testlib.globalFoo()`, or change the function as below.

```
def globalFoo():
    return "the string you want to print"
```

The answer is the same for the other function in the class.

Comment: Super CDspace! :)

Answer (score 1):

When in the globalFoo() function:
    It not only prints out "in global foo",
    the function also returns a 'None'

```
This returned value of None is supplied to your print statement:
    print testlib.globalFoo() is actually:
    print 'None' 

when you call testlib.globalFoo(), within the function, it correctly prints 'in global foo'.
```

The other none is similarly from the returned value of getValue(), which returns 'None'.